# Active MQ showing more than one (ghost) consumer

Tags: activemq-classic

We have a system that uses ActiveMQ (Queues) - and have exactly one producer and one consumer (implemented as a Windows Service in .NET). Over the weekend, the infrastructure team had a reboot of the servers on the network, and from then on we noticed that there are more than one ghost consumer appearing that listens to the queue and we also suspect reads and deletes the messages.

My questions are:

1. is there any way from the Active MQ management console to find out what the consumers are (hostnames, etc). and
2. Are there any scenarios in which inadvertent consumers get 'created'? For instance, there were suggestions about the active MQ journal folders getting corrupted after a reboot, or there is another suggestion that another machine with Active MQ broker automatically makes itself a consumer of all the queues on the main/live active mq server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is way you could know your consumers better. You just need a JMX client (JConsole or VisualVM fits great). All consumer IP addresses and ports exposed in MBean panel on specified queue.